# How to create an adjacency matrix out of a list of integers

Tags: java, adjacency-matrix

Everywhere I look in the internet the adjacency  matrix is made out of either one string or one integer value like so:

```java
public class Graph {
    private boolean adjMatrix[][];
    private int numVertices;
    
    // Initialize the matrix
    public Graph(int numVertices) {
        this.numVertices = numVertices;
        adjMatrix = new boolean[numVertices][numVertices];
    }
}
```

Vertex described as either a string name or integer digit.

[image]

I wanted to know how to make it so my vertex allows a list of ints instead of only one variable.

[image]

Comment: 1. Please don't post images; post code instead; 2. What have you tried to achieve your desired result? maybe it's better to just do something on your own first, and then see, whether you're successful at it, instead of just dropping the question here with "solve my task" attitude?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help with the edits. I'm not looking for someone to solve my task since you can't really do anything with the information provided to solve it. I was looking for tips on how to call the Vertex inside the matrix. things like should I create a class Vertex and define it ass a list ? I did not add any of my own code since I don't really know how to tackle this problem. Sorry if I came around wrong with my post.